# How to grab this specific element with JSoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to webscrape basic info about users on this website. All I want to do is grab the user's name and their respective reputation. Below is a copy of the page's source:

```
    /**Update information about latest job in String array LatestJobInfo.*/
    public void getLatestInfo() {
        Document latest_job = getJob(getLatestID());
        try {

            //Find client
            Elements clientname_fetch = latest_job.select("div.item-listing__username.mt-0.mb-0");
            System.out.println(clientname_fetch);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

https://pastebin.com/dtxvHBEh

I am attempting to scrape the information from lines 288 and 292. I have tried the following and literally got nothing. I think I need to access these elements through their parents first, but I am having trouble doing that. If someone can give me a quick guide on the syntax of grabbing deep elements like these, that would be perfect.

Here is what I have tried:
            Elements clientname_fetch = latest_job.select("div.item-listing__username.mt-0.mb-0");
            Elements clientname_fetch = latest_job.select("h5");

Comment: `.select("h5").text()`?

Comment: Thank you for responding, however, that does not work. I have tried selecting all the 'h5' elements on the page, but it seems that this one is out of the scope for some reason. In addition, getting h5's text does not work because the type of clientname_fetch is "Elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first selector should be `.item-listing__username` and the second one is `.item-listing__avatar__rep`.
In order to get them, I've opened my browser's dev tools (F12), selected the inspector tool (circled with #1), moved the cursor to the target element and clicked it (#2, at this point I could not choose the exact element but it was not a problem). The browser highlighted the line that contains that element (#3) and from there I've navigated down until I've found the username and score -> right click -> copy css selector and that's it.
[image]

Comment: I tried to do this but it does not work. It seems that it is not detected a elements with that class name. I even tried to print out all of the a elements and you can see that no a elements with those class names are printed out.

https://pastebin.com/kEgVZQU5

Comment: You've got me confused - you've accepted my answer, that indicates that it solved your problem, but your comment says it didn't. The html attached to your question contains the above elements in lines 288 and 293. If you don't see them in your program, maybe there is a problem in the way you fetch the html from the server.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your answer is technically correct, but it does not work for my specific case because the content I am trying to grab is dynamic content. There answer is correct and you spent time working on it so I marked it as the answer!